# creating a dynamic triangle which its height should change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have to create a main circle div then by clicking on it it should display its branch circles.

For example maincircle is `M1` and the branch circles be `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, `B4`. On clicking the `B1` circle it should further shows another small circles...

I am struggling here in this part, my question is to create a triangle kind of flow path as it should be dynamic according to the number circle produced...

I am attaching a JPEG for your clearance:

[image]

In this picture you could see some green small circles on the right side.
i have did all these with my codes except that shaded triangle..

Attached picture is photoshoped for creating that triangle shade to the snapshot of my output..

Please get me the solution with the codes

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a website to *provide codes* for. Please make an effort yourself first and post the code that you are using

Comment: Yes. TheDarkKnight is right !  Please try what you can , then post what you tried !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  SO is not a codewriting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. what you need is wery hard with HTML/css alone.
You would propably need to use either a canvas or svg and here you'll have a hard time positioning it right, according to those div-circles.

Personally I'd consider using one of those excellent .JS svg libraries out there.
[Here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/javascript-libraries-animate-svg/) are some examples but many more exists.